# For retrospective observational studies how to determine the baseline of control subjects

Tags: causality, matching, observational-study, control-group, baseline

I understand that for the active treatment group you can consider the start of treatment as baseline. How about the control group?
It is difficulty to do matching without resolving this problem.

Comment: That depends. For example, if the control group undergoes a sham operation, takes a placebo, or has something else done then the baseline for it is at "control treatment" start time. So, in what way is the control group a control? Control of what in your question?

Comment: I see. Thanks. That would be difficult for retrospective studies. These procedures need to be planned prospectively. For example, using natural history studies of untreated patients as an external control to treated patients in a clinical trial. The control subjects are simply untreated patients.

Comment: Need more information.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, the covariates used for matching should be measured contemporaneously for both treatment and control groups, before the treatment has started, but as close to the start as possible.   If the covariates used for matching make the treatment assignment ignorable (loosely speaking, the treatment group and control groups are similar to each other on average EXCEPT for the treatment), making sure you match just before the treatment administration would ensure nothing else changed in the interim and the two groups were comparable, on average, at the time of treatment administration.

Comment: There would be no problem if this is a prospectively planned study. The difficulty is with retrospective study...

Comment: Often, we have pre-treatment covariates available for both treatment and controls even in retrospective studies; examples abound in social science papers.  Of course, if you theoretically know that a particular covariate is important for matching and is not available, you may be in a bind.  Still, all is not lost.  You may be able to match on measured covariates and then follow it up with sensitivity analysis to assess how likely is any observed effect due to the missing covariate. I hope this helps.